# multer: keep original image file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

i'm using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to upload images to an express server, by default multer creates autogenerated/randomized filenames (which is generally good), but in my particular situation i need the filenames to be the same as the original, i've tried the following:

```js
const upload = multer({
  dest: `${__dirname}/path/to/folder`,
  filename: function (req, file, cb) { cb(null, file.originalname) }
})
```

but the images keep getting renamed to multer's randomized name. i've also tried the `destination` property instead of the `dest` ...but same issue.

Comment: Your code is correct, (see: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/439#issuecomment-276255945) I think You're using different upload middleware in place where You want to implement it. Can You add to Your question route handler?

Comment: `multer.diskStorage(` instead of `multer(`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following code.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './assets/images');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('userPhoto');


app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            var FileName = req.file.filename;
            res.status(200).send(FileName);
        }
    })
});
```